# Double CSS background IMG not working

Tags: html, css

I have another problem with my site. I want to add transparent PNG on hover to one of my elements, but I can't manage to get it done. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<a class="item elipsis" href ="https://michalgrochowski.github.io/elipsis---flex/" target="_blank">
<p>PSD to HTML</p>
<p>Flexbox</p>
<p>Fixed heights and widths</p>
 </a>
```

And CSS:

```
.elipsis {
    display: block;
    background-image: url("../img/elipsis.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.elipsis:hover {
    background-image: url("../img/elipsis.png"), url("../img/black50.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Why it doesn't want to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background image that needs to be on top, should come first in the `background-image` value, so if you want to have `elipsis.png` covered by semi-transparent `black50.png` the code should look like this:

```
background-image: url("../img/black50.png"), url("../img/elipsis.png");
```

Comment: Well, they say that the best solutions are often the easiest, I don't know why I couldn't figure it out. Thanks, it's working now :)

Answer (score 1):

you can add more style

> background-image: url("path.png"), url("path.png"); 
>   background-repeat: no-repeat,no-repeat;  background-position: top
>   center, bottom center;